# Cache files (.js and .css) returns data size 0

Tags: browser, browser-cache, sugarcrm

I am using SugarCRM where it creates cache files (.js and .css). The issue is it returns 0 as the size for most of the cache files stored in disk when we see in Firebug.

```
Last Modified   Tue Jun 21 2011 07:43:08 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Last Fetched    Tue Jun 21 2011 07:43:08 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Expires Thu Jan 01 1970 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Data Size   0
Fetch Count 4
Device  disk
```

But when I type the same URL in new tab in browser window, it shows the contents correctly.
This reason the website is not loading the css and js.

I tried to clear the cache in local system using browser still no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete the cache directory in SugarCRM server after you make any changes or alternatively you can repair which will restore the things.

It should solve your issue